# Error with a file name containing parentheses

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

when I tried to change file name from `old.file(1).gz` to `new.file.gz`, It says syntax error, I am using ubuntu 12.04.

```
mv old.file(1).gz new.file.gz
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Try `mv 'old.file(1).gz' new.file.gz`.

Comment: what ubuntu is that? I've never heard of Ubuntu 12.0

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yeti's comment will work for you, but if you would like to know why, it's because parentheses are interpreted as special characters, and have to either be escaped with `\` or the entire filename quoted (as above) [edit: sorry, only the ( and ) need to be quoted].

If you have tab completion enabled, just type the first few characters of the file name and hit tab. I.e., typing `mv old` and hitting tab, should turn into `mv old.file\(1\).gz` (unless there are other potential files that `old*` could refer to).

Comment: The entire file name doesn't need quoting. Only the `()` do. You can do `mv old.fil'e(1).'gz new.file.gz` if you like.

Answer (score 6):

```
mv 'old.file(1).gz' new.file.gz
```

should fix the problem.